# source ~/.vimrc working in file but not automatically source coffee

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, vim, coffeescript, macvim

I have added the coffee syntax and indent plugin for vim. Here is my ~/.vimrc:

```
colorscheme peachpuff
syntax on
filetype on
source /Users/(myusername)/.vim/vim-coffee-script-master/indent/coffee.vim
source /Users/(myusername)/.vim/vim-coffee-script-master/syntax/coffee.vim

au BufNewFile,BufRead *.js set filetype=javascript
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.coffee set filetype=coffee
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.rake set filetype=ruby
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.rb set filetype=ruby
au BufNewFile,BufRead Gemfile set filetype=ruby
au BufNewFile,BufRead Guardfile set filetype=ruby
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.less set filetype=scss

set autoindent
set expandtab
set softtabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
```

This doesn't have the syntax highlighting when I open a .coffee file. I then run `:so ~/.vimrc` while I am in the file and the syntax highlighting appears. Also, when I split the screen and run `:so ~/.vimrc` in one window it disappears in the other. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried putting the syntax file in ~/.vim/syntax?  You shouldn't need to set up autocommands.  I realize that isn't quite what you asked, but might help.

Comment: First, you should get a plugin manager like Vundle. Second, you don't really need to setup the auto commands. Third, if you use Vundle or similar you will not need to source the files manually.

Comment: Also, if you don't want to use Pathogen or Vundle then atleast put it in the correct folder, which would be `~/.vim/indent` and `~/.vim/syntax`.

Comment: Your last comment worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.vimrc` file is for global settings. By sourcing *coffee*-specific scripts in there, you only temporarily apply them to the bare Vim during startup; any files you open aren't affected by it.

Instead, Vim has an elaborate mechanism for detecting various types of programming languages and other file types; cp. `:help filetypes`. Syntax files should be placed into `~/.vim/syntax/` and indents into `~/.vim/indent/`. Then, once you `:setf coffee` (or if there is a detection defined for `*.coffee`), it'll all be automatically activated.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand why they can't be in a subdirectory.